# Transformation of an equation

Tags: math, equation

I'm not unterstanding what I'm doing wrong with this (simple) transformation (solve for Rv):

[image: equation]

I subtracted both sides by I<sub>L</sub>*R<sub>V</sub>, then I divided both side by -I<sub>L</sub>. This is my solution:

[image: equation]

But why is this wrong?

Comment: You've not flipped all the signs you need to flip.

Comment: Tip: EE.SE supports MathJAX directly. Just enclose your equation in `$$ ... $$` tags or `\$ ... \$` for in-line formatting. (Note that on other SE site's it's just `$ ... $` for inline.)

Comment: Where was factor Vd?

Comment: @Transistor Darn. That's nice for a comment. And I just learned how to do it by placing text first as a `blockquote` and then selecting the text in the `blockquote` and clicking on the `code` button. Never saw that trick before. But now I know to use the `acute` mark directly. Always more to learn!